# Is Javascript under V8 faster than equivalent code on other languages?

Tags: javascript, v8

Anyone know whether Javascript on V8 runs faster than equivalent code on other languages such as Python, Perl, PHP etc...?

Comment: What "equivalent code", for example? Speed will always vary depending on the purpose.

Comment: Languages do not have speed. *Implementations* of languages have speed. V8 is an implementation of Javascript, but Python is a language. (Do you mean CPython or IronPython or Jython?)

Comment: By equivalent code I'm referring to code which functionally does the same thing.  When I posted the question I was thinking about Node.js specifically.  By similar code I mean other competing languages.  I think given how V8 works, CPython and Jython should not be out of the question.  I realize languages don't have speed.  However language implementations do have performance characteristics.  I was hoping that would be easily inferred from the post.  Sorry about that.

Comment: In short, V8 is just the best JITing VM for dynamic languages widely available.  If you're really concerned with raw performance, Java/C#/C++ will still blow it out of the water. If you're working with numeric code, NumPy will speed up Python drastically, approaching the levels of compiled languages.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, according to the Computer Language Benchmarks game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=v8), but [be careful interpreting results from artificial benchmarks](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/dont-jump-to-conclusions.php).

The default comparison is to Java, which is generally faster, but you can compare it to Perl, PHP and several Ruby and Python implementations. It seems to be mostly faster except in the benchmarks that use big integers, because JavaScript doesn't support them natively.

Comment: FTFY http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/which-programming-languages-are-fastest.php?v8=on&python=on&jruby=on&php=on&perl=on&yarv=on&calc=chart

Comment: And http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/dont-jump-to-conclusions.php

Comment: @igouy: I actually meant to link to that "don't jump to conclusions page", so thanks :) The other link is useful too.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the application. In same specific cases it's faster than GCC/C++ in the long run.

http://wingolog.org/archives/2011/06/10/v8-is-faster-than-gcc

[image]

> That's right, V8 is always faster than GCC, right up to the point at which its fixnums start failing. For the record, only the points on the right of the graph are really worth anything, as the ones on the left only run for a few milliseconds.
>
> AdamK says:
>
> Seems logical. GCC deals with the code only once, ant after it's done there is no room for improvement. V8 deals with the same code over and over and can improve optimization over time.
>
> You usually compile code with GCC only once. Noone compiles everything everytime he wants to use something. So, comparing compile+run time between V8 and GCC is not fair - GCC has much harder job to do to create good code, because it can't improve it over time.

Answer (score -3):

No. Nobody can beat, performance wise, an implementation of (eg, Node.js) written by an expert who has spent a year implementing it in assembler, with a focus on performance (backed by benchmarks and timing information, which is removed in a release version), for a particular architecture and particular data file.

Of course, the bottleneck is downloading the program, not in the actual runtime performance, however, hand-crafted assembler would still be very hard to beat given its size.

Comment: """Of course, the bottleneck is downloading the program, not in the actual runtime performance, however, hand-crafted assembler would still be very hard to beat given its size.""" This has nothing to do with the question, not to mention that it is wrong.

Comment: On real-sized programs (whose object size is in megabytes), **compilers optimize better than human programmers coding manually assembler code**.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: "real-sized programs" that you refer to are extremely unlikely to have a full-time expert programmer writing a tiny part of it for the whole year, to the exclusion of all other business and personal tasks.  Can I direct your attention to what I *meant*, which is, that the bottleneck is in *downloading* the program?